# How to fix layout_gravity in listview

Tags: android, listview

I am setting layout_gravity of linear layout. I search a lot but found no correct solution.

here is layout.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:id="@+id/lin"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/relative"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:minWidth="250dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/button2">

            <TextView
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:id="@+id/name"
                android:textSize="15dp"
                android:padding="2dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/message121"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:padding="2dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

and This is java code:

```
    if(idnew.equals(id)){

        Toast.makeText(context,"hello",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
       lin.setLayoutParams(params);
    }
```

I am moving parent layout whose is (id=lin) to right side but code not works properly. Please suggest some solution.

Comment: I dont understand what you exactly want to do.If you want to move parent in center.you can do this on xml file.Add layout gravity to center

Comment: I want to move parent layout whose id=lin to right side in listview Adapter . Basically its chat layout and I want to move user own layout to right side by matching id.

Comment: by using layout_gravity it move to right side but i want to it from listview adapter. I show java code above but It not works

Comment: LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            params.weight = 1.0f;
            params.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;

            lin.setLayoutParams(params);            I use this code but not working